# I cannot reach all the elements in an array when splitting a txt file by using "\n" in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I cannot reach all the elements of an array after reading it by using TMPro_InputField in Unity. I am reading a .txt file in another class by using a method that I wrote and trying to compare an array with the .txt file that is read.

This is for reading the file by using `Split("\n")`

```
public void ReadFile()
{
    if(dataLines.Count > 0)
        dataLines = new List<string>();

    rawDataLines = FileManager.fileManagerInstance.mainFile.text.Split("\n");
    foreach(string line in rawDataLines)
    {
        if (line.Contains(",") && !line.Contains("#") && line!="\n" && !dataLines.Contains(line))
        {
            dataLines.Add(line);
        }

    }
}
```

This is for comparing the read .txt file with InputField text.

```cs
arrayConvertedData = inputData.ToArray();
for(int i=arrayConvertedData.Length-1; i>-1; i--)
{
    if (CheckFile.checkFileInstance.dataLines.Contains(arrayConvertedData[i]))
    {
        arrayConvertedData[i] = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: You must debug your code. We neither see what the file contains nor how the text is split, nor which lines are added, etc. Set a break-point and single-step through your code to see what happens.

Comment: Do you think that without debugging my code I'd put it here?

Comment: If you did, then add more context information. The code looks okay so far. The question is: where does the problem occur? When splitting, when checking the conditions for adding the lines or when checking `dataLines.Contains`? We cannot answer this question, but after debugging you should be able to tell.

Comment: There are ways to read in the files as already split into lines. We are blind as to why it doesnt work and more over what you see

Comment: Reading of the content of the file, splitting it and also storing it work perfectly. Also reading the content of the InputField works fine. The problem is that I cannot reach to the last element of the converted array `inputData.ToArray();`.

Comment: Although not the solution but interesting for you, `line!="\n"` is unneccessary. All occurences are filtered away by the `Split`. Consider `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`. It will iterate one less time for each occurence of the empties in the foreach and that will make the first mentioned not needed too. This will make debugging way easier.